# Finding $F$ from a Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> **Exercise**: Define a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the associated Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure verifies conditions: $\mu_F({1})=\frac{1}{4}$,$\mu_F((-\infty,1))=0$,$\mu_F((1,\frac{3}{2}))=1$ and $\mu_F([2,x))=\frac{x}{2}$,$\forall x>2$

$\mu_F({1})=F(1)=\frac{1}{4}$

$\mu_F((1,\frac{3}{2}))=F(\frac{3}{2})-F(1)=1\implies F(\frac{3}{2})-\frac{1}{4}=1\implies F(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{5}{4} $

However I have no idea on how to deal with $\mu_F([2,x))=\frac{x}{2}$,$\forall x>2$
. I am not understanding the aim of the exercise I tried to draw the function and I can see a straight line from minus infinity to one at the height of $\frac{1}{4}$ and then a point at $1.5$ below the $X$ axis $\frac{3}{4}$.

**Question:**

Since the function is not assumed to be either continuous or trivial how should I find the aforementioned function $F$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have $\mu_F((1,3/2))$ reversed - it should be $F(3/2) - F(1)$.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Note that we cannot determine $F=\mu_F((-\infty,x])$ uniquely using only given information. Specifically, we cannot determine $F$ on $[3/2,2]$. Notice that
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}\mu_F([2,x)) =1=\mu_F(2) = F(2)-F(2^{-}).
$$ Here, $F(x^{-})$ denotes left limit of $F$ at $x$. This means that $F$ has a jump discontinuity of size $1$ at $x=2$. Also, note that 
$$
F(x^{-})=\mu_F((-\infty, x)),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$ Hence $\mu_F([2,x))=\frac{x}{2}$ means that $F(x^{-})-F(2^{-}) = F(x^{-})-F(2)+1=\frac{x}{2}.$ Since $F(x^{-}) = \frac{x}{2} +F(2) -1$ is continuous on $x>2$, we have
$$
F(x)=F(x^{-})  = \frac{x}{2} +F(2) -1, \quad\forall x>2.$$

To conclude, $F$ has the following form
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}0 ,\quad x<1\\1/4,\quad x=1\\ 5/4,\quad x=(\frac{3}{2})^{-}\\ 5/4+\delta ,\quad x=2^{-}\\9/4+\delta,\quad x=2\\5/4+\delta +\frac{x}{2},\quad x>2,
\end{cases}
$$where $0\leq\delta<\infty.$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87411/discussion-on-answer-by-song-finding-f-from-a-lebesgue-stieltjes-measure).